# How do I concatenate the items from the list into a comma delimited string in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this subquery which is part of a larger query. I want the column called ErrorType in the left hand side to be populated by comma delimited set of values returned by the List on the right hand side. How can i do it ? ErrorTypes is a master whose Key is ErrorTypeID and Value is ErrorTypeName. ProductionErrors is the transaction table whose key is Production ID (supplied by outer query), and whose matching key is ErrorType.

```
ErrorType =  (from errorType in db.ErrorTypes 
              join prdErrType in db.ProductionErrors 
              on errorType.ErrorTypeID equals prdErrType.ErrorTypeID
              where prdErrType.ProductionID==prd.ProductionID
              select errorType.ErrorTypeName).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help though it is not part of SO etiquette. One of your many answers helped me.

Comment: The issue was that this was just one assignment among many in a LINQ query. So i could not break out of the format above, given my limited LINQ. So one of the answers worked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be better to use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) in such scenario:

```
ErrorType = string.Join(",", (from...)); // you can omit .ToList() perhaps
```

Answer (score 0):

you should query something like::

```
ErrorType =  (from errorType in db.ErrorTypes join prdErrType in db.ProductionErrors on errorType.ErrorTypeID equals prdErrType.ErrorTypeID
                                              where prdErrType.ProductionID==prd.ProductionID
                                              select new 
                                              {
                                               ErrorType=errorType.ErrorTypeName.tostring()+','
                                               }).ToList()
```

This is because sometimes LINQ to SQL doesn't support string functions.

Comment: I should have mentioned that ErrorType is a string. Your answer would have worked but i was using a string as the output variable.

Answer (score 0):

`string.Join` is the way I would do this, as in the answers that have already been given. But as with most things, there are multiple ways to do it. Another way is using the `IEnumerable<T>.Aggregate` method:

```
var query = (from errorType in db.ErrorTypes 
             join prdErrType in db.ProductionErrors 
             on errorType.ErrorTypeID equals prdErrType.ErrorTypeID
             where prdErrType.ProductionID==prd.ProductionID
             select errorType.ErrorTypeName);

string errorType = query.Aggregate((result,next) => result + "," + next);
```